# Where do I put Pluralization rules in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, entity-framework

I want to add specialized Pluralization rules to my project as I have names in my database like FAS and other things that end with "s" and I want those to be FAS and FASs but the default pluralization wants to make it FASes or something similar which I dont want. I am then trying to use this guide http://blogs.msdn.com/b/efdesign/archive/2008/12/02/pluralization.aspx but I have a hard time figuring out where to put this code? How do I make sure this code is run at startup of my project (I suppose it has to run at startup?)

So where do I put this code?

```
PluralizationService pluralizationService =  
    PluralizationService.CreateService( 
        new CultureInfo("en-US"));

ICustomPluralizationMapping mapping =  
  pluralizationService as ICustomPluralizationMapping;

if (mapping != null) // it shouldn't be but just checking 
{ 
    //Specifying the child pluralizes as children 
    mapping.Add("FAS", "FASs"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is in the tutorial: you have to use it with the schema generator to create the schema using the pluralization service:

```
EntityModelSchemaGenerator generator = 
    new EntityModelSchemaGenerator( 
        storageModel,   
        "MyNamespace", 
        "MyContainer",  
        pluralizationService);

//Generate CSDL and MSL (in memory) 
generator.GenerateMetadata();
```

Comment: Is that already in my code? If yes then where do  I find that?

Answer (score 0):

When do you need to get the names of the entities pluralized?

I may be way wrong, but it seems to me that you could simply add the tables to the model and just rename them in the designer.

Am I overlooking some information?

Comment: The thing is that we (Our team) have many models, and we dont want to rename them each time we make a little change to them, so we would like the edmx file to be created with the correct names when we click "Update Model from database" and add our tables, its very error prone that we have to edit so many tables, if we forget one then hell breaks loose when its named "FASses" instead of "FASs"

Comment: @Mech0z: EF designer will preserve your name changes when you do "Update Model from database". I'm doing this all the time. Give it a try.

Comment: If I for example change one tables data so one of the columns is no longer nullable then if I just use the "Refresh" instead of "Add" then it dont update the model, so I have to delete it and add table again and now the name is not preserved.

Comment: That is another issue. If you just add a new column to a table, you can do the "Refresh" and a new property will be added to your model and the entity name will remain the one you have set, as well as all the changes you've made (rename properties, add table hierarchies, etc.). When you make changes to a column you shouldn't delete the entity on the model - that will lose all of your changes. Instead, you need to make the same change on the designer.